# How to share images with whatsapp in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, share, whatsapp

I have WordPress website and I want to allow my visitors to share images using whats app with android and iOS. I try to find code, but works nothing. Any idea can help me a lot.

Please help me to do this.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Whatsapp does not provide a share button like Facebook does, but there is a 3th party implementation

http://whatsapp-sharing.com/